# Object Detection on KITTI (strange aspect ratio)

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I am trying to train any object detector on the KITTI dataset which has a strange aspect ratio ~370 height and 1240 width.  I am not able to get good detections after starting a fine tuning of any of the models in the model zoo.  I have taken the sample coco configs and simply changed the image resizer arguments to the input image size and changed the number of classes to 4.

I start by creating a TFRecord file of the dataset as directed to in the tutorial and have inspected the file to confirm that the image, label, and other information was correctly saved into the binary format so the dataset is not the problem.

When I evaluate with the models from the zoo, I get decent detections.  However as soon as I try to evaluate on a model I have trained myself, the detections are terrible and are all over the image.  The loss also is extremely low during training, for ssd ~.4 and rfcn ~.0004.  I assume this has something to do with the image size but I am not sure.  Does anyone know why detections would end up being this poor on a new dataset?

Here is an example of the types of bounding boxes I get out from the ssd model:

example detection

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was with the TFRecord file.  The bounding boxes coordinates and labels had the wrong key so the network was being trained on "empty" images with no bounding boxes.  This also explained why my error was converging to 0 because the network's weights were just being squashed by the regularization with no loss from the localization to form gradients.

Comment: since this solves the problem, you can accept it as an answer (the green tick below the score)